# Logging Response time in Yesod

Tags: haskell, logging, yesod

I would like to log the amount of time a request takes in Yesod.

I think I can do this with something like the following:

```
yesodMiddleware handler = do
          t1 <- liftIO $ getCurrentTime
          addHeader "Vary" "Accept, Accept-Language"
          authorizationCheck
          h <- handler --may need to seq this?
          t2 <- liftIO $ getCurrentTime
          -- unsure about this part
          $(logInfo) "Some string that includes t2-t1"
          h
```

Am I missing something? Is there a better way?

There used to be a "timed" function in Yesod.Logger but I can't figure out where it has gone

Comment: I don't know yesod, but that generally looks reasonable. But why don't you abstract it into a function taking an action and returning an action that produces both the underlying result and the time it took?

Comment: @dfeuer thanks! Is it necessary to deepseq the handler?

Comment: Seems unlikely that this is the best approach: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/wai-extra-3.0.2.1/docs/src/Network-Wai-Middleware-RequestLogger.html#detailedMiddleware' might be closer to what is required

Comment: Richard: I agree, a WAI middleware would make more sense here than a Yesod middleware.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a small Wai Middleware you can use to time requests:

```
-- Network/Wai/Middleware/RequestTimer.hs

module Network.Wai.Middleware.RequestTimer (
    requestTimer,
    ) where

import Prelude
import Network.Wai
import Data.Time (getCurrentTime, diffUTCTime)

requestTimer :: Middleware
requestTimer app req sendResponse = do
    t0 <- getCurrentTime
    app req $ \rsp -> do
        t1 <- getCurrentTime
        putStrLn $ "The request time is " ++ (show $ diffUTCTime t1 t0)
        sendResponse rsp
```

I then added this module to `exposed-modules` in my `.cabal` file

```
library
    exposed-modules: Application
                     Foundation
                     Import
                     -- lots more here
                     Network.Wai.Middleware.RequestTimer
```

Then in `Application.hs` I apply the middleware:

```
import Network.Wai.Middleware.RequestTimer

makeApplication :: AppConfig DefaultEnv Extra -> IO Application
makeApplication conf = do
    foundation <- makeFoundation conf

    -- Create the WAI application and apply middlewares
    app <- toWaiAppPlain foundation
    return $ requestTimer app -- Note that you can chain multiple middlewares together here.
```

Now when making requests, you'll see

```
The request time is 3.014697s
```

printed in console.

I'd like to explain the middleware more but I honestly have no idea how it's working—I'm just cropping stuff from [`RequestLogger`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/wai-extra-3.0.2.1/docs/src/Network-Wai-Middleware-RequestLogger.html#detailedMiddleware') and the other Wai middlewares. Hopefully I can get a better understanding of it tonight and come back and edit this answer with details, but I'm about to be late to work.

Comment: PSA: This is no longer necessary if you use [Network.Wai.Middleware.RequestLogger.OutputFormatterWithDetails](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/wai-extra-3.0.26.1/docs/Network-Wai-Middleware-RequestLogger.html#t:OutputFormatterWithDetails).